# SSRS - Pass parameter from one drop down menu to another

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

having a hard time phrasing the title. ok

I've got two attributes, parent and child. The report I'm building asks for these at the start, so I have two dropdown menus, we'll just say @parent and @child
 now, parent only has 50 values to choose from, which isn't too bad. however, child has about 1000 - which is way too much for the dropdown to be effective. it's pulling all available options from that table
 what I would like to do is when you select a row from parent in the dropdown, the list in the child dropdown updates

is there some way to pass the parameter around to do this? my last resort option is to put a table on the report that shows the child's available values and have them link to the report.. but ew, that's terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who runs across this problem:

there are two queries, one for each dropdown

the child's query uses the parent's value from the parent's table - it updates just fine

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  FYI, this is called cascading parameters.